# Generate random numbers in 7 columns where the sum of the 7 columns should be equal to the value given in another column(cell)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to generate random values (say between 0-12) in 7 consecutive columns which I have achieved with the formula -> `=RANDARRAY(,7,0,12,TRUE)`

However I want the sum of these numbers to match the value of the number given in a cell. Example:
[image]

Requirement - In the image, the sum of random values generated in the cells D4:J4 should match C4 likewise for other rows.

Any help to solve this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Karthik S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub test_this()

    Dim num As Integer, low As Integer, hi As Integer, m
    Dim hi2 As Integer, trgt As Integer, t As Integer, y As Long

    num = 7
    low = 0
    hi = 12
    For y = 4 To 9
        trgt = Cells(y, 3)
        If low * num <= trgt And hi * num >= trgt Then
            t = -1
            hi2 = hi
            If trgt < num Then hi2 = trgt
            Do Until t = trgt
                m = WorksheetFunction.RandArray(1, num, low, hi2, True)
                t = WorksheetFunction.Sum(m)
            Loop
            Cells(y, 4).Resize(, num).Value = m
        Else
            Cells(y, 4).Resize(, num).Value = "Err"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I had to add a little trap in there, in case the target figure wasn't achievable using the parameters - but provided you stick to starting at zero I think this will work every time.

---

Taking Tom's suggestion into account, the following version adjusts the lower limit where the target is in the top range so it doesn't take several minutes to find target of 84, for instance:

```
Sub test_this_2()
    
    Dim num As Integer, low As Integer, low2 As Integer, hi As Integer, m
    Dim hi2 As Integer, trgt As Integer, t As Integer, y As Long
    
    
    num = 7
    low = 0
    hi = 12
    For y = 4 To 9

        trgt = Cells(y, 3)
        If low * num <= trgt And hi * num >= trgt Then
            t = -1
            hi2 = hi
            low2 = low
            If trgt < num Then hi2 = trgt
            If trgt > hi * (num - 1) Then low2 = Int(hi * 0.7)
            Do Until t = trgt
                m = WorksheetFunction.RandArray(1, num, low2, hi2, True)
                t = WorksheetFunction.Sum(m)
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Cells(y, 4).Resize(, num).Value = m
        Else
            Cells(y, 4).Resize(, num).Value = "Err"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Apart from the declarations being all missing, this is a good answer :)

Comment: As with my answer the number of iterations would go up exponentially if you tried with a target of (say) 80, but you could also adjust the lower limit if you wanted to allow for this.

Comment: Declarations added.  My copy-fu was off yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a brute-force solution with a lambda:

```
=LET(r, RANDARRAY(1, n, min, max, TRUE), IF(SUM(r) = total, r, generate(n, total, min, max)))
```

Called as

```
=generate(n,total,min,max)
```

e.g.

```
=generate(7,40,0,12)
```

where n is the number of numbers to be generated, total is the required total and min and max are the limits.

[image]

Looks like this in name manager

[image]

Here it is in OP's context - there is no point in generating numbers more than (e.g.) 1 if the total has to be 1.

[image]

This is fairly well-behaved but there is always a possibility of breaching Excel's limit on recursion with lambdas.

*EDIT*

You could also make a correction to the lower limit:

```
=generate(7,C2,MAX(0,C2-72),MIN(C2,12))
```

which would allow you to generate random numbers adding up to (say) 83. The worst cases (sometimes requiring too many recursive calls resulting in a #NUM! error) are going to be around 12 and 72 because the possibilities of {0,0,0,0,0,0,12} and {12,12,12,12,12,12,0} have to be considered, requiring the full range of numbers to be generated.